# Apache Camel in Wildfly Cluster?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, apache-camel, wildfly

We have a need to deploy an enterprise app that makes use of Apache Camel within a Wildfly/JBoss EAP cluster.  Our routes are comprised of things that should only be processed ***once***, which creates a problem when the Apache Camel is started in each node within the cluster.  These are things like file system operations, Amazon SQS integration, etc.  That said, how can we deploy an app in this scenario without duplicating the processing being performed by Apache Camel?

Comment: Could you clarify what makes your application not support a cluster? How do you trigger your routes?

Comment: Polling web services, streaming a Twitter feed, etc.  In those scenarios, the routes would duplicate work, since they would be created on each node in the cluster where the app was deployed.

Comment: Have you considered this doc at all? http://camel.apache.org/clustering-and-loadbalancing.html basically you would use a queue or something to distribute messages out, that queue would be clustered and all clients configured to read from it.  only the one that receives the message does the work.

Comment: Interesting.  But how does this help when you need to poll a RESTful service every 60 seconds (for example)?  Something like from("myendpoint://myservice?poll=60000").to("foo://bar")?  If you deploy this route on 2 nodes, each node is going to poll every 60 seconds.

Comment: That's the thing, you don't do the invocation directly.  The poll puts a message on a queue.  Both servers poll this queue for the need to poll.  You use quartz to do the polling so that it can retain its cluster state.